# iOS - Unable to parse date string "31-07-2014 00:00 BST" to get string 08-31-14 using NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios

Need to convert date string to different format

original: dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm BST
Expected: MM-dd-yy

Tried below code, but not working

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];

dateFormatter.dateFormat =  @"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm BST";

NSDate *dateFormat = [[NSDate alloc] init];

dateFormat = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yy"];
NSLog(@"formatted date: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFormat]);
return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFormat];
```

Comment: `NSDate *dateFormat = [[NSDate alloc] init];` is useless. Just declare the type `NSDate *dateFormat;` And what you mean by not working? What output do you receive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
NSString *dateString = @"31-07-2014 00:00 BST";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"BST"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyyHH:mm 'BST'"];

NSDate *dateFormat = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFormat = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yy"];
NSLog(@"formatted date: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFormat]);
```

What I did here is I set the proper time zone for the source NSDateFormatter and then parsed the date according to it. Look at the setDateFormat. I use single quotes to indicate, that a static string is part of the date format.

It could be written more dynamically to determine the correct time zone, but some string splitting would be required.

I hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an empty NSDate (*dateFormat) when you are formatting, which means there is nothing to format for the date formatter. It is empty because you reallocate it and reinitialise it, meaning you reset all contents of the variable. Give a value to NSDate and then it will work fine

Comment: This makes no sense. It does not matter if dateFormat was initialized or not here, but it does matter if dateFromString returns a value. So you're partially right and partially wrong.

Answer (score 0):

@user1088267

### Method:1

```
NSDate *currentDate=[[NSDate alloc]init];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.YY HH:mm:ss BST "];

NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate;

NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
```

### Method :2

```
NSDate *currentDate=[[NSDate alloc]init];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yy HH:mm:ss BST "];

NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate;

NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `dateFormat`:

```
dateString = @"31-07-2014 00:00 BST";
...
dateFormatter.dateFormat =  @"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm BST"; // wrong format
...
// this makes dateFormat to become nil
dateFormat = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
...
// pass nil here
NSLog(@"formatted date: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFormat]);
```

Your date formatter can not parse your string, because it has wrong format and returns `nil`. Then you use `nil` in `-stringFromDate:` and print `nil` in `NSLog`. You can work it out by fixing your date format like this:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm 'BST'"; // note 'quotes'
```

But this is bad practice, because you loose time zone info. `z` (or `V`, not sure why) as timeZone formats won't work, because `BST` is a meta timezone. As a workaround you could set a timezone of your date formatter and perform conversions.

You can read about format patterns [here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns), add this page to your bookmarks if you didn't.

Also you don't need to allocate unnecessary object to use the pointer:

```
// this is useless, you create pointer to NSDate, create/init NSDate instance
// and make that pointer to point to created instance
NSDate *dateFormat = [[NSDate alloc] init]; 
// here you make dateFormat to point somewhere else -dateFromString: returns
// causing ARC to delete your NSDate instance created on the previous line
dateFormat = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

// so, you just want:
NSDate *dateFormat = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```