# NSDateFormatter printing one year earlier dates

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsdateformatter, date-formatting

Below is what I have.

```
NSString *dateString = @"08/27/2014 04:00:00 PM";
NSLog(@"dateString---%@", dateString);
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"dateFromString===%@", dateFromString);
```

Below are the NSLog.

```
dateString---08-27-2014 04:00:00 PM
dateFromString===2013-12-22 13:00:00 +0000
```

I am not getting what I am doing wrong here. Why date is print 2013 year and that too with wrong dates?

---

Actually I have date string as `8/27/2014 4:00:00 PM` and using formatter as `M/dd/YYYY h:mm:ss a`. Still its giving same problem.

Comment: Refer this link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362333/ios-unable-to-parse-date-string-31-07-2014-0000-bst-to-get-string-08-31-14/25362758#25362758

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `YYYY` should be `yyyy`:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
```

Just tested this and it works for me.

Reference: [Link](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: great... but hours are coming wrong... it says 13:00 instead of 16:00 (4 PM)

Comment: Hmm. I'm guessing that's a timezone related issue because it's saying 21:00 for me.

Comment: @EFE well whose problem is that?